# iOS conversions not importing from branch to Google ads (the same Android conversions successfully import)

Tags: ios, branch, google-ads-api, branch.io

Has anyone else had any issues with importing downstream conversions from Branch to Google specifically with iOS?

While we have been able to import basic conversions (i.e. first opens) across iOS and Android, Google Ads only allows us to import android custom conversions and NOT iOS despite both conversions firing from the same event (there isn't even an option to import these iOS conversions in Google). Anyone know of any possible solutions?

We've tried refreshing Link IDs, reauthenticating, and creating other conversions but we continue to run into the same issue of iOS conversions not being passed back into Google.